# "Nothing to be done for makefile" message

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following files:

`Child.c , Cookie.c , Cookie.h , CookieMonster.c , Jar.c , Jar.h, Milk.c , Milk.h`

and the following makefile, named `makePractice`, which is supposed to create two executables, `Child` and `CookieMonster`.

```
makefile:

CC = gcc    # the compiler
CFLAGS = -Wall  # the compiler flags
ChildObjects = Jar.o    # object files for the Child executable
CookieMonsterObjects = Jar.o Milk.o     #object files for the CookieMonster executable

all: Child CookieMonster    # the first target. Both executables are created when 
                # 'make' is invoked with no target

# general rule for compiling a source and producing an object file
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

# linking rule for the Child executable
Child: $(ChildObjects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ChildObjects) -o Child

# linking rule for the CookieMonster executable
CookieMonster: $(CookieMonsterObjects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CookieMonsterObjects) -o CookieMonster

# dependance rules for the .o files

Child.o: Child.c Cookie.h Jar.h

CookieMonster.o: CookieMonster.c Cookie.h Jar.h Milk.h

Jar.o: Jar.c Jar.h Cookie.h

Milk.o: Milk.c Milk.h

Cookie.o: Cookie.c Cookie.h

# gives the option to delete all the executable, .o and temporary files

clean: 
    rm -f *.o *~
```

When I try to use the makefile to create the executables, by running the following line in the shell

```
make -f makePractice
```

I get the following message:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `makefile'.
```

I don't understand what's wrong...

Comment: Why do you have `makefile:` at the top? Remove that!

Comment: Hint: Try to make the "all" target.

Comment: `make -f makePractice Child` maybe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't specify a target on the command-line, Make uses the first target defined in the makefile by default.  In your case, that is `makefile:`.  But that doesn't do anything.  So just remove `makefile:`.

Comment: So simple! I love you stackoverflow! :D

Comment: Thanks for save my time.. +1

Answer (score 6):

Your command line does not tell `make` what you want to be made, so it defaults to trying to make the first explicitly named target in the makefile. That happens to be `makefile`, at the very first line.

> makefile:

Since there are no dependencies, there is no reason to do anything to remake that file. Therefore `make` exits, happy at having obeyed your wish.